# sum of value with distinct date sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Table_4

```
accid0v subst0v actd0v  pric0v
12001   10  11/19/2013  10.99
12002   10  11/20/2013  10.99
12003   10  11/21/2013  10.99
12004   20  11/21/2013  20.99
12005   10  11/21/2013  10.99
12006   30  11/26/2013  20.99
12007   40  11/26/2013  10.99
12008   10  11/26/2013  5.99
```

I want output

```
actd0v       pric0v
11/19/2013    10.99
11/20/2013    10.99
11/21/2013    42.97
11/26/2013    36.98
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select actd0v,sum(price0v) from Table_4 group by actd0v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  actd0v,  sum(pric0v) from  Tablename GROUP BY actd0v
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select
  actd0v,
  sum(pric0v) pric0v
from
  YourTable
GROUP BY actd0v
```

Answer (score 0):

You need group by clause

```
select actd0v,sum(price0v) from Table_4 group by actd0v
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select actd0v,sum(price0v) from Table_4 group by actd0v
```